# Android: How to Get location updates in background

Tags: android, service, background, location

I request location updates using `fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates()` in `onStartCommand()`. It works fine. But when I close the app or kill the app, `onLocationResult()` is not called.

Comment: Already had an answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066540/android-location-updates-in-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ForegroundService. Here's the complete code for doing exactly what you want:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService